# SQL Query to compare two columns with one column equal to a column in another table and second column is not equal to the second column from t2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-query-store

Table structure is as below

t1 PK:(id,item)

| id | item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

t2 PK:(id,item)

| id | item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |

output expected:
t1

| id | item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |

I tried the below query but it didn't work, I am getting all records of t1 whereas the expectation is only those are not matching in t2,
Note: I am trying it without using sub query

```
select 
    a.id, a.item 
from 
    t1 a, t2 b, 
where 
    a.id = b.id and b.item <> b.item;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Also, your condition `and b.item <> b.item` can ***NEVER*** be true .....

Comment: I have also tried with JOIN instead of old-style joins, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic in your `WHERE` clause can be made to work if we rephrase your query using exists:

```sql
SELECT id, item
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM yourTable t2
    WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.item = t1.item
);
```

Comment: Thank you. I keep forgetting about using this in cases where I have two columns that will sometimes have identical values. Thank you very much.